# maximum spanning tree in a complete graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures, spanning-trees

Given a [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) how do I find maximum weight spanning tree.
where $weight(u, v) = \sum_{i=1}^{k} |w_{i,u} - w_{i,v}|$

- assuming $k \lt 7$ and $n \le 500000$.
- $n$ number of nodes
- $weight(u,v)$ means weight from node $u$ to $v$
- $w_{i, u}$ is given for $i < k$ for a give node $u$
- $k$ is some constant.

Comment: Your explanation doesn't make a lot of sense. Please define what $k$ is.

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. I think the problem is with *spanning tree*: you seem to be looking for a *sub-graph* without saying so explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would simply be to negate the weight of all edges, and then run an algorithm such as Prim's or Kruskal's, which work with negative edges.